# DevExpress set focus to specific row of VerticalGrid

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

My code to set the focus to a specific row of the VerticalGrid is not working.

```
this.ActiveControl = vGridControl1;
vGridControl1.Focus();    
vGridControl1.FocusedRow = vGridControl1.GetRowByFieldName("addr1");
```

I have confirmed that `vGridControl1.GetRowByFieldName("addr1")` returns the correct row.

The first row contains a ButtonEdit, and that is where focus always goes.

The grid is in MultiRecordView but at this point contains only one (new) blank record. Adding

```
vGridControl1.FocusedRecord = 0;
```

before setting the FocusedRow doesn't make a difference.

What step am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this which worked for me...

```
    vGrdSummary.Focus()
    vGrdSummary.FocusedRow = vGrdSummary.Rows("rowNatureOfLoss")
```